# Exception: Cell reference out of range expiredsubsalt @ Code.gs:824

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running this code and getting same error after trying different data values.
please help me resolve this error.

```
function expiredsubsalt()  // Function to Move expired members from Active Memberships to Expired Membership Sheet
// put the variable to pick the last row and last column and put it into expired sheet
{
  var schedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Active Memberships");
  var archive=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Expired Memberships");
  var clno = schedSheet.getLastColumn();
  for(r=schedSheet.getLastRow();r>1; r--) //For loop started for all rows
  {
    
    if (schedSheet.getRange(r,9).getValue()== "Expired")
    { 
      archive.getRange(2,1,archive.getLastRow(),archive.getLastColumn());
      archive.appendRow(schedSheet.getRange(r,1,1,clno).getValues()[0]);
      schedSheet.deleteRow(r);
    }
   if (schedSheet.getRange(r,2).getValue()==""){schedSheet.deleteRow(r)}    
  }

  Logger.log(r)
  Logger.log(clno)
   // archive.getRange('A2:I').removeDuplicates();
   // archive.getRange().sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);

    archive.getRange(r,clno).removeDuplicates();
    archive.getRange(r,clno).sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);

  
}
```

line no 824 is  - archive.getRange(r,clno).sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);

Comment: Your code is trying to sort one cell, I think that's why it can't find second columns to sort to

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines:

```js
archive.getRange(r,clno).removeDuplicates();
archive.getRange(r,clno).sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);
```

the `r` variable is being used is the same that was previously used to loop through the first file, and it has a value of `2` regardless of your spreadsheets. Moreover, as it has been said,your code is trying to sort only one cell.

As you probably want to sort and remove duplicates the whole `archive` spreadsheet, I would suggest changing the ranges to something like:

```js
.getRange(1,1,archive.getLastRow(), archive.getLastColumn())
```

You can read more about how Google Sheets deals with ranges [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and how you can provide different inputs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).